# Protobuf dependency in ROS Fuerte/MacOSX

Tags: java, ros-fuerte, rosjava, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to compile my ROS node.  This node compiles perfectly fine in Unix (running ROS Electric).  Now, I am trying to compile it in Mac (running ROS Fuerte).  The node depends on Google Protobuf, and I have installed protobuf successfully and also compiled my .proto file successfully.  However, when I try to make my ROS node, I get some errors:

> Linking CXX executable bin/mylib
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "_main", referenced from:
> start in crt1.10.6.o
> "google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::generated_pool()", referenced from:
> protobuf::protobuf_AssignDesc_maverick_5fcmd_2eproto()      in maverick_cmd.pb.o
> "google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::FindFileByName(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&) const", referenced from:
> protobuf::protobuf_AssignDesc_maverick_5fcmd_2eproto()      in maverick_cmd.pb.o
> "google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::LogMessage(google::protobuf::LogLevel, char const*, int)", referenced from:
> protobuf::protobuf_AssignDesc_maverick_5fcmd_2eproto()      in maverick_cmd.pb.o
> protobuf::CommandObj::MergeFrom(protobuf::CommandObj const&)in maverick_cmd.pb.o
> protobuf::CommandObj::MergeFrom(google::protobuf::Message const&)in maverick_cmd.pb.o

The list of errors continues for quite some time... it's doubtful that this helps, but here is the full list of errors...

> Linking CXX executable bin/mylib
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_main", referenced from:
>       start in crt1.10.6.o
>   "google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::generated_pool()", referenced from:
>       protobuf::protobuf_AssignDesc_maverick_5fcmd_2eproto()      in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::FindFileByName(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&) const", referenced from:
>       protobuf::protobuf_AssignDesc_maverick_5fcmd_2eproto()      in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::LogMessage(google::protobuf::LogLevel, char const*, int)", referenced from:
>       protobuf::protobuf_AssignDesc_maverick_5fcmd_2eproto()      in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>       protobuf::CommandObj::MergeFrom(protobuf::CommandObj const&)in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>       protobuf::CommandObj::MergeFrom(google::protobuf::Message const&)in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::operator, std::allocator > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)", referenced from:
>       protobuf::CommandObj::SerializeWithCachedSizes(google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*) const in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteFloat(int, float, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)", referenced from:
>       protobuf::CommandObj::SerializeWithCachedSizes(google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*) const in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteDouble(int, double, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)", referenced from:
>       protobuf::CommandObj::SerializeWithCachedSizes(google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*) const in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::SerializeUnknownFields(google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)", referenced from:
>       protobuf::CommandObj::SerializeWithCachedSizes(google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*) const in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::ReadVarint32Fallback(unsigned int*)", referenced from:
>       protobuf::CommandObj::MergePartialFromCodedStream(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*)      in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::ReadString(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, std::basic_string, std::allocator >*)", referenced from:
>       protobuf::CommandObj::MergePartialFromCodedStream(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*)      in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::ReadLittleEndian32Fallback(unsigned int*)", referenced from:
>       protobuf::CommandObj::MergePartialFromCodedStream(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*)      in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::ReadLittleEndian64Fallback(unsigned long long*)", referenced from:
>       protobuf::CommandObj::MergePartialFromCodedStream(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*)      in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::SkipField(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, unsigned int, google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet*)", referenced from:
>       protobuf::CommandObj::MergePartialFromCodedStream(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*)      in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::ReadTagFallback()", referenced from:
>       protobuf::CommandObj::MergePartialFromCodedStream(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*)      in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::ClearFallback()", referenced from:
>       protobuf::CommandObj::Clear()     in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::~UnknownFieldSet()", referenced from:
>       protobuf::CommandObj::~CommandObj()in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>       protobuf::CommandObj::~CommandObj()in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>       protobuf::CommandObj::~CommandObj()in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>       protobuf::CommandObj::CommandObj(protobuf::CommandObj const&)in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::Message::~Message()", referenced from:
>       protobuf::CommandObj::~CommandObj()in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>       protobuf::CommandObj::~CommandObj()in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>       protobuf::CommandObj::New() constin maverick_cmd.pb.o
>       protobuf::CommandObj::~CommandObj()in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>       protobuf::CommandObj::CommandObj(protobuf::CommandObj const&)in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>       protobuf::CommandObj::CommandObj()in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>       protobuf::CommandObj::CommandObj()in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>       ...
>   "google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::UnknownFieldSet()", referenced from:
>       protobuf::CommandObj::New() constin maverick_cmd.pb.o
>       protobuf::CommandObj::CommandObj(protobuf::CommandObj const&)in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>       protobuf::CommandObj::CommandObj()in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>       protobuf::CommandObj::CommandObj()in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>       protobuf::protobuf_AddDesc_maverick_5fcmd_2eproto()      in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::internal::VerifyVersion(int, int, char const*)", referenced from:
>       protobuf::protobuf_AddDesc_maverick_5fcmd_2eproto()      in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::InternalAddGeneratedFile(void const*, int)", referenced from:
>       protobuf::protobuf_AddDesc_maverick_5fcmd_2eproto()      in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::MessageFactory::InternalRegisterGeneratedFile(char const*, void (*)(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&))", referenced from:
>       protobuf::protobuf_AddDesc_maverick_5fcmd_2eproto()      in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::internal::OnShutdown(void (*)())", referenced from:
>       protobuf::protobuf_AddDesc_maverick_5fcmd_2eproto()      in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::MessageFactory::InternalRegisterGeneratedMessage(google::protobuf::Descriptor const*, google::protobuf::Message const*)", referenced from:
>       protobuf::(anonymous namespace)::protobuf_RegisterTypes(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)in maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::Message::GetTypeName() const", referenced from:
>       vtable for protobuf::CommandObjin maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::Message::InitializationErrorString() const", referenced from:
>       vtable for protobuf::CommandObjin maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::Message::CheckTypeAndMergeFrom(google::protobuf::MessageLite const&)", referenced from:
>       vtable for protobuf::CommandObjin maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::Message::DiscardUnknownFields()", referenced from:
>       vtable for protobuf::CommandObjin maverick_cmd.pb.o
>   "google::protobuf::Message::SpaceUsed() const", referenced from:
>       vtable for protobuf::CommandObjin maverick_cmd.pb.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> make[2]: *** [bin/mylib] Error 1
> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/all] Error 2
> make: *** [all] Error 2

I'm thinking that the errors have something to do with the protobuf dependency.  Also, I have a file in my node ./libs/libmylib.so, and I don't actually know what the purpose of this file is, but it is referenced in my CMakeLists.txt file...

> rosbuild_add_library(mylib src/maverick_cmd.pb.cc)

Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34981/protobuf-dependency-in-ros-fuerte/macosx/) by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) on ROS Answers with karma: 227 on 2012-05-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you linking against the protobuf library? Is it, per chance, only built for 32-bit (or only 64-bit) and you're building everything else using the other architecture?

(Tangential: why protobufs? ROS messages serve the same purpose...)

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) on 2012-05-27**:
Could you expand a bit?  It's possible that I am not linking against the protobuf library, but I'm not exactly sure how.  On your other comment, I am using protobuf is because I am using a GUI written in Java and communicating through a socket with ROS. I am open to other solutions if you have them.

**Comment by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) on 2012-05-27**:
Could you expand a bit?  It's possible that I am not linking against the protobuf library, but I'm not exactly sure how.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-05-27**:
ROSJava is a (potentially) better solution to that problem. Do you have a target_link_libraries somewhere in your CMakeLists?

**Comment by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) on 2012-05-28**:
ROSJava is a great idea!  However, I am also having problems with that.  I have also made a post about that issue here: http://answers.ros.org/question/34857/rosjava-on-macos-fail-to-build-roscore/ .  I have target_link_libraries(publisher protobuf) in my CMakeLists.  Is this correct?

**Comment by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) on 2012-05-28**:
Thanks a lot for the help, Mac.  Your idea inspired me to add the line "rosbuild_add_library(publisher src/maverick_cmd.pb.cc)", which fixed the issue.  I do agree that rosjava is a better solution, but this is my fallback in case I can't get that working.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-05-28**:
Glad I could help. Upvote and accept my answer? (Karma!)